# WKHTTPCookieStore getAllCookies doesn't always call completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift

Our application allows logging in via SSO, which we do by firing up a WKWebKit view to a particular URL that communicates to our server, and eventually redirects to a URL that we are expecting. During this process we get a cookie that we need to transfer to our SessionManager, however, when trying to get the cookies from the WKHTTPCookieStore, we don't always get the callback. Here is some code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    let httpCookieStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore
    httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
        // This block not always called!!!
    }
}
```

This typically happens on initial install of the app on device, and is reproducible almost always on device, but not in the simulator.

At this point I have tried everything I can think of, but I don't know why the callback is sometimes called but not always.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly this behaviour. At first I thought it was just on (or shortly after) app launch, but it just seems that sometimes the completion handler just doesn't get called at totally random times. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I ended up having to work around this issue... our server redirects but includes token info in the URL, so I had to extract that value and create a SessionCookie manually, then add that cookie to our session. 
`let cookieProperties: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any] = [.name : sessionName, .value : token, .domain: url.host, .path : "/"]`  

`self.sessionCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties)`  


Then elsewhere,  
`SessionManager.default.session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(self.sessionCookie!)`

Comment: I eventually found that the completion block would only be called if a WKWebView was present on screen. If not, the blocks would be queued until a webview was visible again. The workaround involved a hidden webview tucked away in the corner of the screen. Not elegant, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

To see all cookies you can use this code

```
import UIKit

import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero,configuration:configuration)
    self.view = webView
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let url = URL(string: "YOUR URL")

    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    webView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: [.new, .old], context: nil)

    self.webView?.load(request)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if let newValue = change?[.newKey] as? Int, let oldValue = change?[.oldKey] as? Int, newValue != oldValue {

        print("NEW",change?[.newKey])
    } else {
        print("OLD",change?[.oldKey])

    }

    webView?.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
        for cookie in cookies {
            print(cookie)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that `configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies` does NOT always call the completion block. `WKNavigationDelegate` gives us plenty of chances to look for URL redirects